# How to store picture in sqlite table?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.android, blob, mvvmcross

I'm trying to store a picture in sqlite table. I'm using mvvmcross vnext and its plugin sqlite.

I have this class Image for the table "Image" in the database :

```
public class Image : Model
{
    [IsNullable(false)]
    public int ImageID { get; set; }

    [IsNullable(false), MaxLength(100)]
    public string UrlImage { get; set; }

    [IsNullable(false), MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I need to add a property for the picture data.
Do I store the picture in `byte [ ]` format ? (I heard of "`BLOB`")
It's possible to do that with the ORM ? Or Do I need to do that directly with sql query ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store files, including images, in a byte[max] column. Read the bytes of the image file and write them to that column in the DB.

Comment: I didn't think it was so simple. Thanks you

Answer (score 2):

For SQLite-net, this test class provides some good examples of reading writing byte arrays - https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/tests/ByteArrayTest.cs

It uses a data class like:

```
public class ByteArrayClass
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public byte[] bytes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I did the same and I create a custom binding to display picture as byte[] to imageView

Comment: @liotims - I would be very very interested in your binding ;-)